# get request params in middleware handle

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-routing, laravel-middleware

I'm going through [HTTP Middleware manual](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/middleware). And have created a middleware "LogAll" and added it to `$middleware` array in `Kernel.php`.

Everything works fine, except I don't have request params (post or get) in the `handle` method of `LogAll`

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    var_dump($request->all());
    return $next($request);
}
```

it prints an empty array. When calling a url that matches this route:

```
Route::get('/{id}', ['as' => 'profile', function($id) {
    return $id;
}]);
```

Note that, I have added a route pattern in `boot` method that checks `id` to be numeric.

Answer (score 2):

For retrieving route parameters you should use `route()`:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    echo $request->route('id');
    return $next($request);
}
```

Comment: it throws an error: `FatalErrorException in Request.php line 674: Call to a member function parameter() on a non-object`

Comment: That's because global middleware runs before routing happens. What is that you want to accomplish?

Comment: logging all requests. (just for testing purpose)

Comment: Then I'd just log `$request->uri()` or create a middleware that runs after the request has been processed.